# Callback for native JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to attach a callback to native JS function. For example when `Array.prototype.push('d')` gets called, I want to fire another function. Is it possible?

UPDATE:

```
function Dummy() {};

Dummy.prototype = Array.prototype;
var arrObj = new Dummy(); 

var domElement = 'itemsList';

arrObj = ['werew', 'werewr', '234324'];


(function(native) {
    arrObj.push = function() {
        native.apply(this, arguments); 
        arrObj.render(domElement);
    };
})(arrObj.push);



arrObj.addItem = function(item) {
    this.push(item); //Uncaught TypeError: this.push is not a function
    this.render(domElement);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Normally you shouldn't be modifying native functions unless you have a really good reason for it.

Comment: It seems you have some confusions. First you declare `arrObj` as a non-array object which inherits from `Array.prototype`, and then you overwrite it with a real array. So the former is useless.

Comment: I'm assigning it Array prototype so that I can overwrite array methods with actually effecting Array.

Comment: I think you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/npz9hamm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hijack it with your own function:

```js
(function(native) {
  Array.prototype.push = function() {
    native.apply(this, arguments); // Redirect call to the native function
    // Do something here
  };
})(Array.prototype.push);
```

Comment: @JS-JMS-WEB You are not following the code in this answer and JavaScript is case sensitive.